# UINavigationBar becomes transparent after switching views in uitabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

In the `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method, I initialized an instance of UINavigationController with `GeneralOptionsTableViewController` and an instance of `GeneralOptionsMapViewController`. The navigationBar color was set to green. However, when I switch between the UINavigationController with `GeneralOptionsTableViewController` and `GeneralOptionsMapViewController`, the navigationBar becomes transparent. I tried resetting the navigationbar color in the `viewWillAppear` method but it does not seem to work.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    GeneralObjectTableViewController *generalObjectTableViewController = [[GeneralObjectTableViewController alloc] init];
    GeneralObjectMapViewController *generalObjectMapViewController = [[GeneralObjectMapViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:generalObjectTableViewController];
    navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];


    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, generalObjectMapViewController, nil]];

    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong this code, it works on me as expected.

Comment: Are you re-initializing it every time it is shown?

Comment: @JoePasq, what do you mean by re-initializing, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` called one time

Comment: @mstfbsnli the code works when I am switching between views without an instance of MKMapView. But if I switch to `generalObjectMapViewController`, the navBar becomes transparent.

Comment: I assume not, but do you call `[[GeneralObjectMapViewController alloc] init]` ever again? As in do you destroy the variable and then create a new one?

Comment: I think it's a bug from apple, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080459/mkmapview-affecting-uinavigationbar-and-tabbar-appearance)