# iOS 7 Translucent Tab Bar and Nav Bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I am having an issue with the translucent `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar` in iOS 7, whereby if I only have the `UINavigationBar` translucent it works as I would expect it to, however as soon as set the `UITabBar` to translucent I get a strange effect happening in one out the four tabs in the app. Let my explain with some images:

This image shows the interface where only the nav bar is set to translucent:

[image: UINavigationBar translucent only (1).]

With this image showing the result of the user scrolling the content up and under the nav bar:

[image: UINavigationBar translucent only (2).]

Now, this is how I would expect it to look, and when the user scrolls the content back from under the nav bar it looks as it did before.  However if I also set the `UINavigationBar` to translucent, and scroll the content to under the nav bar, the result is different to the second image:

[image: UINavigationBar and UITabTab translucent (1).]

Event the tab bar doesn't look right to me.  This next image shows that the look of the nav bar if now different to what it was before, when the content is scrolled back from underneath it:

[image: UINavigationBar and UITabTab translucent (2).]

Again, I also don't thing that the look of the tab bar is correct, as the next image shows a different tab with content underneath it, with only a subtle change to the look of the tab bar:

[image: UINavigationBar and UITabTab translucent (3).]

Has anyone else had similar issues to this? (This is all set up in a storyboard)

Comment: You should share some code, if not it is not easy to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Gabriel.Massana I have posted an answer to my question below, to which sharing code would not have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this was an annoying one. I added a fifth tab which had a `MKMapView` in it. On running the app and selecting the fifth tab, the tint colour from the nav and tab bars was removed, so I did a search and came across [MKMapView affecting UINavigationBar and UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080459/mkmapview-affecting-uinavigationbar-and-tabbar-appearance)

The test device I was using had iOS 7.0.2 on it, which falls in line with the bug mentioned; so have therefore updated it to the 7.1, and low and behold everything looks as it should.